Another "Failed to launch the browser process"
Puppeteer works fine on the old server but I spent the last 2 days trying to figure out why browser won't launch on the new one that runs Cloudlinux 8, cPanel, Node 22 and the latest version of Puppeteer. I managed to isolate the problem in the following script.
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: '/home/my_user_folder/.cache/puppeteer/chrome-headless-shell/linux-128.0.6613.119/chrome-headless-shell-linux64',
    headless: true,
    args: [
      //'--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--disable-software-rasterizer',
      '--single-process',
      '--user-data-dir=/home/my_user_folder/tmp/puppeteer_user_data'
    ]
  });
  console.log('Browser launched!');
})();

No matter what I try, I always receive this error.
/home/my_user_folder/nodevenv/my-app/22/bin/node /home/my_user_folder/my-app/public/damnit.js
/home/my_user_folder/nodevenv/my-app/22/lib/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:312
                reject(new Error([
                       ^

Error: Failed to launch the browser process!


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting

    at Interface.onClose (/home/my_user_folder/nodevenv/my-app/22/lib/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:312:24)
    at Interface.emit (node:events:532:35)
    at Interface.close (node:internal/readline/interface:527:10)
    at Socket.onend (node:internal/readline/interface:253:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:532:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Node.js v22.1.0

ldd chrome | grep not is fine. There's nothing missing in my browser. Permissions should also be fine since I spent the last 2 days chmodding everything hundrends of times. Browser doesn't start even when I run it directly as follows:
/home/my_user_folder/.cache/puppeteer/chrome-headless-shell/linux-128.0.6613.119/chrome-headless-shell-linux64/chrome-headless-shell --headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage

And this is the result:
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

This is what I have in dmesg | grep chrome:
[580949.894828] traps: chrome-headless[2619634] trap int3 ip:55a569dabe26 sp:7fff5226c820 error:0 in chrome-headless-shell[55a5645a3000+884a000]
[580977.732416] traps: chrome-headless[2619676] trap int3 ip:5569e11d1e26 sp:7ffc950fffa0 error:0 in chrome-headless-shell[5569db9c9000+884a000]
[581190.516838] traps: chrome-headless[2620505] trap int3 ip:55779955de26 sp:7fff273bc5a0 error:0 in chrome-headless-shell[557793d55000+884a000]
[582336.563613] traps: chrome-headless[2623748] trap int3 ip:5636a6218e26 sp:7ffcdb58fd60 error:0 in chrome-headless-shell[5636a0a10000+884a000]

I followed all suggestions described on https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting, on GitHib and reinstalled all the things multiple times including older versions. Any help would be appreciated.

This question is similar to: Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
